# How to stop loading animation after 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a loading screen and a fading up page like here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5. The problem is that I don't know how to end the loading loop and make that fading.

Codes

```
        <body>
            <div class="sk-chase">
                <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
                <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
                <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
                <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
                <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
                <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
            </div>
         </body>
body {
        background-color: #636e72;
    }sk-chase {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      animation: sk-chase 2.5s infinite linear both;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .sk-chase-dot {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0; 
      animation: sk-chase-dot 2.0s infinite ease-in-out both; 
    }.sk-chase-dot:before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width: 25%;
      height: 25%;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 100%;
      animation: sk-chase-dot-before 2.0s infinite ease-in-out both; 
    }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: -1.1s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: -1.0s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: -0.9s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: -0.8s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: -0.7s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: -0.6s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(1):before { animation-delay: -1.1s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(2):before { animation-delay: -1.0s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(3):before { animation-delay: -0.9s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(4):before { animation-delay: -0.8s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(5):before { animation-delay: -0.7s; }
    .sk-chase-dot:nth-child(6):before { animation-delay: -0.6s; }
    @keyframes sk-chase {
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
    }
    @keyframes sk-chase-dot {
      80%, 100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
    }
    @keyframes sk-chase-dot-before {
      50% {
        transform: scale(0.4); 
      } 100%, 0% {
        transform: scale(1.0); 
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the JavaScript that tells the browser when to hide the loader and show the content. See snippet below

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.querySelector("#loader").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector("#myDiv").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #636e72;
}

.sk-chase {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  animation: sk-chase 2.5s infinite linear both;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  position: absolute;
}

.sk-chase-dot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: sk-chase-dot 2.0s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

.sk-chase-dot:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: sk-chase-dot-before 2.0s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(1):before {
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(2):before {
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(3):before {
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(4):before {
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(5):before {
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
}

.sk-chase-dot:nth-child(6):before {
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
}

@keyframes sk-chase {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes sk-chase-dot {
  80%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes sk-chase-dot-before {
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.4);
  }
  100%,
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div id="loader" class="sk-chase">
    <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
    <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
    <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
    <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
    <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
    <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
    <h2>Tada!</h2>
    <p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`animation: sk-chase 2.5s infinite linear both;`

Word `infinite` is your problem. Use a number of reps instead `infinite`. In your case is 1.

Comment: Okay thanks, it works, but when the loop ends there is a dot left on the page, any clue how to hide it? Sorry if it's quite stupid, but im newbie in front-end.

Comment: This example has everything you need https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5 .
The first, there is two elements on page. The first is, that your will see late, the element with text:

Comment: The second is element, there animation is:

Comment: <div id="loader">

Comment: And the third thing is the function that performs the switch. Switch is - in the begin, element with text have attribute "display: none", so it's invisible. But element with animation in normal condition, without "display:none". And in the end of animation this function invert this condition - block with animation obtain "display: none" and block with text gets "display: relative" or "display: flex" or something else, what will make him visible.